# Primefaces OneMenu, Internet Explorer and JAWS

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

I have a problem with Primefaces "OneMenu" and JAWS with Internet Explorer. JAWS only reads the selected value, but it does not read the label for the menu.

Do you have any ideas? How can I solve this problem?

Versions:

- Internet Explorer 11  (11.0.9600.18376)
- JAWS 17.0.2619 (August 2016)
- Primefaces 6.0

Comment: Look at the generated html, look at the wai-aria specs and check if PrimeFaces implemented it correctly. And also check in the issue list if it maybe is already solved in 6.0.1 or 6.0.2. If you know what is wrong, you can override the PrimeFaces renderer for this component and fix it.

Comment: Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome works perfect! The wai-aria specs are correct, I checked it already. But it does not work with Internet Explorer...

Comment: Ok so this is effectively not a PrimeFaces related issue?Then it is for the jaws-screen-reader people maybe more interesting if you post the generated client-side html for this component. Without this they cannot do much

Comment: I forgot the link to the primefaces showcase - I'm sorry:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Comment: It seems to be an JAWS issue! I tried http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/11/, it does not work too!